# jquery mobile CSS

Tags: css, jquery-mobile

I want to be able to swap the jquery mobile CSS for a desktop "friendly" CSS. For example when a user is NOT on a mobile device display the styles in a non mobile type style. Is there a platform or existing CSS that does this?

Comment: You want [css media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries). However, jQuery Mobile isn't quite like regular HTML, and uses a lot of unique JavaScript to boot, so if you don't want the JQM "feel" of navigating the site, you'll have to start over from scratch.

Comment: Or server detection for mobile vs tablet vs desktop devices/browsers to determine what file to load in. I've found that to be an effective method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just change the mobile version css to looks good in desktop.

**CSS3 Media Queries**

*Some Examples:*

**Max Width** - 
If the viewing area is smaller than 600px.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .class {
    background: #ccc;
  }
}
```

**Min Width** - 
The following CSS will apply if the viewing area is greater than 900px.

```
@media screen and (min-width: 900px) {
  .class {
    background: #666;
  }
}
```

**Multiple Media Queries** - 
Combine multiple media queries. The following code will apply if the viewing area is between 600px and 900px.

```
@media screen and (min-width: 600px) and (max-width: 900px) {
  .class {
    background: #333;
  }
}
```

**Device Width**
The code will apply if the max-device-width is 480px (ex. iPhone display)

```
@media screen and (max-device-width: 480px) {
  .class {
    background: #000;
  }
}
```

**Link to a separate stylesheet:**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen and (max-width: 600px)" href="small.css" />
```

Comment: Hey I did flag this aa a good answer but I ran across this article http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn296507.aspx